# SAP FIORI Media list to download from SMP

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-erp

Can anybody tell me what exact media we have to download for **SAP FIORI** for **ECC 6.0**

Thanks 
Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

Good answer. In addition you could check [Fiori Apps Library](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/)  for specific apps.